# Creating an exchange if it does not exist with Logstash

Tags: rabbitmq, logstash

I created a Logstash instance that has a RabbitMQ input. I specified the key, exchange and queue in the configuration of Logstash.

When looking at the RabbitMQ web interface some time later, I realized that the exchange and queue used by Logstash weren't automatically created in RabbitMQ. Is there a way to tune Logstash to create the exchanges and queues it needs in RabbitMQ, without having to create them with the web interface?

Comment: You're not setting `passive => true` for the input are you? If not the queue should've been created for you. Howeer, you shouldn't expect the exchange to be created. A consumer doesn't declare an exchange.

Comment: The queue has been created but not the exchange. I guess I'll let the producer declare the exchange...